# Best way to convert cloudformation serverless template into Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm trying to convert a `serverless framework` YML file into a Terraform script.

It's my first time with `terraform` and I don't have much experience with infra either.

I'm getting some errors with my Terraform but my question is more about my approach.

Is there a better/simpler/smarter way to write the same serverless yml in Terraform ?

**Maybe modules out there which would make my life easier.**

**Terraform**

```
# Lambda invoke function role data
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_invoke_function_role" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    sid     = ""
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      service = "lambda.amazonaws.com"
    }
  }
}

# Lambda ec2
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ec2_lambda_policies_role" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    sid    = ""
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
      "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
      "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
      "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
    ]
    resources = "*"
  }
}

# Lambda allow invoke
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_invoke_role" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    sid    = ""
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    ]
    resources = "*"
  }
}


# Lambda invoke function role
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_invoke_function_role" {
  name               = "lambdaRole"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda_invoke_function_role.json}"
}


# EC2 ##############################################################################
resource "aws_iam_policy" "ec2_lambda_policies_policy" {
  name               = "ec2LambdaPolicy"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.ec2_lambda_policies_role.json}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ec2_lambda_policies_policy_attachment" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_invoke_function_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.ec2_lambda_policies_policy.arn}"
}
###############################################################################


# Allow Invoke #####################################################################
resource "aws_iam_policy" "allow_invoke_policy" {
  name               = "allowInvokePolicy"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow_invoke_role.json}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "allow_invoke_policy_attachment" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_invoke_function_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.allow_invoke_policy.arn}"
}
###############################################################################


# Lambda invoke function role policy attachment
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "aws_lambda_basic_execution_role" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_invoke_function_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
}

# Lambda invoke function role policy attachment
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "aws_lambda_vpc_access_execution_role" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_invoke_function_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
}
```

**Serverless YML (cloudformation)**

```
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Path: '/'
      RoleName: LambdaRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: ec2LambdaPolicies
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  - ec2:DetachNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                Resource: "*"
        - PolicyName: 'AllowInvoke'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: 'Allow'
                Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
                Resource: '*'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
```

Comment: fair enough. I will update the question.

Comment: Im going through the errors. That's why I wanted to find a better approach. It seems something quite common to be done. So, why not reusability on those things.

Comment: I did some research trying to find popular modules but no lucky

Comment: Removing anything related to errors to avoid misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [cf-to-tf](https://github.com/humanmade/cf-to-tf) which will convert cloudformation into terraform.

```
cf-to-tf --stack foobarbaz config | json2hcl | cf-to-tf clean-hcl | terraform fmt -
```

That will import your stack `foobarbaz` from AWS and convert it into terraform and print it to stdout.

Comment: I didn't think about something like that before. That's a good point, even to understand how my infra should be setup in terraform. I will give a try

Comment: I have more than 400 lines of cloudformation to convert. Very good shout.